# c# mysql utf_8_general_ci and password hashing

Tags: c#, mysql, node.js, hash, cryptography

I have a sha512 password hash that is generated by a nodejs web server, which for some reason c# isn't interpreting it correctly.

The hash in the db is:

```
09d5c4cfdf9449bba5c8f36f6feba141e91467d2602388930f2b4ec36939e60c3d81f6aec07ebdcab74c67d7c99e516521b5565e09ea547d66dc460a80b06b4e
```

The hash that C# consoles out is:

```
09d5c4cfdf9449bba5c8f36f6feba141e91467d2602388930f2b4ec36939e60c3d81f6aec07ebdcab74c67d7c99e516521b5565e09ea547d66dc460a80b06b㐀攀
```

As you can see the last two characters are non utf8.

MySQL stores the hash in a utf8_general_ci table. Here is the snippet of code which queries for the information.

I read somewhere that c# string is utf16 by default, and i'd guess thats the problem, how can i fix this?

### C Sharp

```
Command.CommandText = string.Format( "SELECT username, password FROM {0} WHERE state='{1}'", DatabaseTable, ( int )Status.Pending );
OdbcDataReader reader = Command.ExecuteReader( );

QueryCount += 1;

while( reader.Read() ){
    string username = reader.GetString(0);
    string password = reader.GetString(1);
    Console.WriteLine("Password from DB Is: {0}", password);
```

Comment: 1) Don't use SHA-512 to hash passwords, it's too fast. Use a proper password hash like PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt. 2) Use some form of parameterized query instead of building a query string.

Comment: While I agree with you CodesInChaos this is simply out of my depth for C#. Some of this code is nearly 7 years old, and not written by me.. Believe me if i could easily adapt bcrypt i would.